# What type of value does Blender use for the Point Rotate Node when set to Attribute?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I really dont understand what value type Blender uses for this node.
I have tried many diferenr values but dont understand.

The nodes I am usign:
[image]

The rotation when the value is 1:
[image]

The rotation when the value is 2:
[image]

The rotation when the value is 3:
[image]

Thanks, hope someone can help!

Comment: It uses angles measured as radians, not degrees.

Comment: Oh, thanks! just some time ago learned about radians.

Comment: @nathan For me to mark this question as like "done" without a answer but a comment, sould you add your comment as a answer and if so could you ad it as an answer?

Comment: Last time I added an answer that short, it just got moved to a comment, despite solving the poster's problem, so I'm not going to bother.  If you want to mark the question as done, you can feel free to post your answer and mark it.

Comment: Okay, thank you!